# Does exist a Banach-Tarski paradoxical decomposition of the unit cube in which each piece has the Baire Property?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

The Banach-Tarski Paradox for the cube states that the open unit cube in three dimensions can be decomposed into finitely many pieces, which can then, by rotation and translation, be re-assembled into two copies of the unit cube. That is, there exist disjoint sets $\left(A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots, A_{n}, B_{1}, \ldots, B_{m}\right)$ whose union is $(0,1)^{3}$ and there exist Euclidean isometries $\left(\rho_{1}, \rho_{2}, \ldots, \rho_{n}, \sigma_{1}, \ldots, \sigma_{m}\right)$ such that
$$
(0,1)^{3}=\bigcup \rho_{j}\left(A_{j}\right)=\bigcup \sigma_{i}\left(B_{i}\right)
$$
Clearly the pieces $\left(A_{1}, \ldots, A_{n}, B_{1}, \ldots, B_{m}\right)$ cannot all be Lebesgue measurable, because Lebesgue measure is preserved by rotation and translation.

The problem of Marczewski for the cube (which is some sixty years old) asks: Does there exist a Banach-Tarski paradoxical decomposition of the unit cube, in which each piece has the Baire Property?

Although little is known about this question, it seems reasonable to conjecture that the answer is no. First of all, it is unlikely that the proof of the Banach-Tarski Paradox, which uses the Axiom of Choice to define the pieces, could be modified so that the pieces have the Property of Baire. Furthermore, a positive answer to Marczewski's Problem would imply the following, seemingly implausible conclusion. Any cube, no matter how small, contains pairwise disjoint open subsets $U_{1}, \ldots, U_{n}$ such that, for suitable isometries $\rho_{i}$,
$\bigcup \rho_{i} U_{i}$ is dense in the unit cube.
Every hyperfinite von Neumann algebra is an injective $\mathrm{C}^{*}$ -algebra. It is very plausible to conjecture that each hyperfinite monotone complete $\mathrm{C}^{*}$ -algebra is injective. However, seems that that if this is true then there exists a paradoxical decomposition of the open unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^{n}(n \geqslant 3)$ into pieces with the Baire Property.

Comment: I've removed the category theory tag (Baire category has nothing to do with category theory).

Comment: Other than repeating a conjectural question, do you have your own mathematical question?

Comment: Who is this Marzewski? You don't mean the famous Polish mathematician [Edward MARCZEWSKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Marczewski), do you?

Comment: @bof yes, it's him.

Comment: In that case, I edited your question to correct the spelling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marczewski's question was answered affirmatively (!) for the unit ball in:

Randall Dougherty and Matthew Foreman.
Banach—Tarski decompositions using sets with the property of Baire.
Journal of the American Mathematical Society, vol. 7 (1994), pp. 75–124.

The result can surely be transferred to the cube.

Edit: In the last sentence, "surely" (which usually means "I'm confident but haven't checked") can be upgraded: Dougherty and Foreman state the expected extension, to arbitrary bounded, open, nonempty subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n\geq 3$, on the first page of their paper.